# Restrict the status in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have started to learn Oracle Apex, and I follow this document - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-spreadsheet-hol-5532109.pdf

I can't understand why on page 27 they use this query

```
select distinct status d, status r 
from spreadsheet
order by 1
```

They use status twice on one table

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generating values for a select list. The first column is what is displayed in the select list and the second the value returned when selected. In this case both columns are the same but that isn't required

Comment: Both are required, query doesn't work without both of them. Can you explain more? please

Comment: Also, when I selected for example open, I got duplicate values

Comment: "**In this case** both columns are the same but that isn't required" (as chrisis said) means that select list's query must have exactly two columns: display and return value. Usually, they are different, e.g. `select employee_name as d, employee_id as r from emps`. In some cases both display and return values are the same, just like in example you found in documentation. As of duplicate values you got for "open" (that's a status, I presume), where did you get duplicates? In some report that uses select list's "status" value? If so, fix report's query.

Comment: @Littlefoot After selecting one of them in list, I get all values, but with different order

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If possible, edit your question and attach a screenshot, along with some sample data and query that returns that result.

Comment: I understand now :D